# Getting "This app is in development mode", when launching an app live on FB

Tags: facebook

I think I have everything right, but my app is not live. It says "This app is in development mode" I guess that is what they used to call sandbox mode, but I don't see where to take it off of development mode. Can someone please help me
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I guess Facebook changed something again. Development and live mode got replaced by something called 'access-levels'. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels/)

Answer (score 71):

The solution that onkar has posted did not work for me. I think that the Facebook app interface has changed since onkar's solution was posted.

Here is what worked for me:

1) Go to https://developers.facebook.com

2) From the top nav bar select: Apps >> Your App Name >> App Review

3) At the top of the Status & Review page you should see "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" with a toggle (no/yes) switch.

4) Click the toggle switch so it displays "Yes".

Comment: For me it was necessary to add my email to make the button be available.

Comment: Now they have renamed "Status & Review" to  "App Review"

Answer (score 33):

I am not able to make my app live.

Because:

At the top of the Status & Review page I am not able to toggle yes...
 "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"

something I'm missing... after some research I solved the problem by adding developer mail id.[image: see the image]

Answer (score 8):

in May 2016 here's how we do it:

[image]

1) Go to https://developers.facebook.com

2) From the top nav bar select: Apps >> Your App Name >> App Review

3)  At the top of the Status & Review page you should see "Make {App_name} public?" with a toggle (no/yes) switch.

4) Click the toggle switch so it displays "Yes".

Answer (score 8):

as per the latest UI in Facebook Developer Account - you need to go App Review Tab/Menu at the left bar - 5th position from top.
[image]

This answer was posted on Date 5-12-2016

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
Apps>>Your App Name >> Basic



Basic Info will have 

Display Name:

Namespace:

Contact Email:

App Domains:

Sandbox Mode:
Enabled/Disabled **Select the Disabled RadioButton** to make your application live
```

Comment: Thanks @onkar, but I don't have sandbox mode as a choice to enable or disable.

Comment: Please can you share screen shot of the basic tab of your app

Answer (score 0):

JUst follow mentioned steps:
1. Fill the basic info  as you already filled.
2. Sandbox mode should be disabled else other then app user no one can use that .
3. In app domain mention the domain /subdomain name  Eg.  If u are using it from localhost of your system then

App Domain should be : localhost.

Note - > Beware of entering http or www in app domain name

1. Then if you want to use "Website with Facebook Login" then in Site URL : 
   enter the site url and that should be under the domain name.. For localhost if domain then 
   enter in Website login : `http://localhost/`
2. Save all changes and you are done . Just use the app id and secret key in your app and its ready to rock and roll..