# Facebook Share from my app

Tags: android, facebook

I want share content on Facebook from my app.
When i click share button it should login and share content from dialog.
Login is Working fine, But i don't know how share without default share button from Facebook SDK

My Facebook login code as follows

```
final ProfileTracker[] mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker[1];
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication with Facebook failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication with Facebook failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: you can use ShareDialog just check documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: Need to give witePermissions to share on facebook??

Comment: no you dont need .. unless you need to create your own custom dialog or share programmatically without using the ShareDialog provided by facebook API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After successful login use `ShareLinkContent` to share on facebook wall :

**code** :

```
 if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new   ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setContentTitle("Any Title")
                               /* .setContentDescription(
                                        "'Hello Facebook'")*/
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"))
                                .build();

                        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                    }
```

In  onSuccess method of LoginManager use this peice of code.

and initialize `ShareDialog` and `CallbackManager` in **onCreate** of `Activity` like this :

```
callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            shareDialog=new ShareDialog(this);
            shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new   FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                }
            });
```

and `onActivityResult` method of Activity add callback manager :

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
```

Comment: its not sharing on my Facebook wall

Comment: what error is coming try to log it out in onError method of `shareDialog`

Comment: "event.returnValue is deprecated"  but i have added onActivityResult.but still same error is coming

Comment: Add callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in onActivityResult method of Activity i am editing my answer check it out

Comment: i have added callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in onActivityResult but still same issue. and in onActivityResult  resultcode is return as "-1". i get full profile info only sharing but not possible.

Comment: publish_actions is required to share?

Comment: @android check your key hashes, possibly case of key hashes mis-match and according to facebook doc **Your app does not need to request the publish_actions permission in order to use the Feed Dialog** doc url - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-publish_actions please check your keyhashes and status of your app on facebook dev portal, app should be live http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696738/i-am-new-how-do-i-make-my-app-live-on-fb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100122/discussion-between-kapil-rajput-and-android).