# Android - grant facebook permission issues

Tags: android, facebook

I am working in project that needs to publish some articles , I am struggle to find way to publish some text without permission but I fail then I decided to grant publish_actions , I stuck with this error

> You need to test this permission in your app with any account listed
>   in Roles before you can submit for review. It looks like you haven't
>   tested this permission because no API request has been made against
>   publish_actions in the last 30 days.

[image]

after search I find I must test this permission before grant it

```
List<String> mReadPermissions = Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile", "user_friends");
    List<String> mPublishPermissions = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


          _loginfb.setReadPermissions(mReadPermissions);
        _loginfb.setPublishPermissions(mPublishPermissions);
        _loginfb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                final Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("fields", "id, email, name, picture.type(large)");

                System.out.println("Success callback");
                GraphRequest mRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                if (response.getError() != null) {
                                    // handle error
                                    Log.i(TAG, "ERROR");
                                } else {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Success");
                                    String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                                    Log.i("JSON Result", jsonresult);

                                    LoginWithFB(json);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                mRequest.setParameters(params);
                mRequest.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
```

But I got this error

> Cannot call setPublishPermissions after setReadPermissions has been
>   called.

any one can guide me how to grant steps I am using facebook sdk 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in `facebook docs` you can't use `publishPermission` with `readPermission` [Facebook dev doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginButton/#setReadPermissions)

According to the doc's

> The LoginButton can only be associated with either read permissions or
>   publish permissions, but not both. Calling both setReadPermissions and
>   setPublishPermissions on the same instance of LoginButton will result
>   in an exception being thrown unless clearPermissions is called in
>   between.

so after Successfull login and getting response from `Graph api` call `loginbutton.clearPermissions();` to set `PublishPermission`

**Code :**

```
_loginfb=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fblogin);

    _loginfb.setReadPermissions(mReadPermissions);

    _loginfb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            final Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "id, email, name, picture.type(large)");

            System.out.println("Success callback");
            GraphRequest mRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                            _loginfb.clearPermissions();
                            _loginfb.setPublishPermissions(mPublishPermissions);
                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                // handle error

                            } else {

                                String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);



                            }
                        }
                    });
            mRequest.setParameters(params);
            mRequest.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }


    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: I need ask for publish permission on publish article only but I cant could you have snap code doing this function

Comment: @MinaFawzy please check my updated answer, call `clearPermissions()` to set `PublishPermissions` after successful login and getting user info in response i.e. in `onCompleted`

Comment: thanks man , this solve my problem but I still have this red alert

Comment: u'r welcome , do publish any post from your app by login from an account as mentioned in **Roles** ,go through this link for clarity https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit#testpermissions

Comment: thanks mate , please share example code of how can I publish any text to wall if you can

Comment: use `ShareDialog` to share on wall , check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651882/facebook-share-from-my-app/34652223#34652223